# How to do encrypt encoded data instead of plain data using AES 128 in python 3

Tags: python, aes

I am new in python so I have no idea about encryption and encoding so guys please help me how to encode data using base64 first and then encrypt that encoded data using AES 128 bits and it will do in python 3.

key_size = 16 bits and,
block_size = 16

My question is not simple as you predict. My question is that first encoding -> encrypting. Is it possible or not ?

Comment: This makes no sense.  The whole point of Base64 is that it allows arbitrary binary data to be converted to textual form, so that it can be transmitted through a text-only channel.  However, most computer encryption algorithms produce binary output even if the input was text, thus losing any point in doing the Base64 encoding - all you've accomplished is making the encrypted data larger.  Base64 encoding *after* encryption is a lot more reasonable.

Comment: @jasonharper yes it is reasonable but thiis is not the requirement. Developers makes possible anything and have flexibility according to the requirements.

Comment: @HarshithThota It looks like duplicate but here I described my problem  that Base64 Encoding is doing first and then encryption that text which is get after encoding

Comment: @HarshithThota These links are useless because python3 needs key and data as in bytes object so errors are shown when use these links you mentioned so please try to understand my problem.

Comment: please guide me in right directions